# How to rewrite this knapsack javascript function using C# code?

Tags: c#

I am trying to rewrite the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71187391/what-is-wrong-in-this-knapsack-problem-solution) using c# code. As C# doesn't have spread, and we get out of bounds exceptions, it's been a difficult task. I managed to write the following code, its working, but i believe there is a better way of doing this.

```
 int? result = MaxCollectableTreasure(new List<int?>() {1, 3, 1, 8, 7 }, 3);
    
    int? MaxCollectableTreasure(List<int?> chests, int minutes)
    {
        if (chests.Count == 1 && minutes > 0)
            return chests[0];
    
        int? firstElement = chests[0];
        var restOfList = chests.Skip(1).Take(chests.Count).ToList();
    
        return MaxCollectableTreasuresRecursive(firstElement, restOfList, minutes);
    }
    
    int? MaxCollectableTreasuresRecursive(int? firstElement, List<int?> chests, int minutes)
    { 
        if (minutes == 0 || firstElement is null)
            return 0;
    
        if (firstElement == 0)
            return MaxCollectableTreasuresRecursive(chests.FirstOrDefault(), AllButFirst(chests), minutes - 1);
    
        var left = firstElement + MaxCollectableTreasuresRecursive(0, AllButFirst(chests.Prepend(0)), minutes - 1);
        var right = MaxCollectableTreasuresRecursive(chests.FirstOrDefault(), AllButFirst(chests), minutes - 1);
    
        int leftAsInt = left ?? 0;
        int rightAsInt = right ?? 0;
    
        return Math.Max(leftAsInt, rightAsInt);
    }
    
    List<int?> AllButFirst(IEnumerable<int?> chests)
    {
        return chests.Skip(1).Take(chests.Count()).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Questions asking for improving complete, working code without specific, objective metrics are off-topic here. Consider asking on the Code Review site instead. Alternatively, in a way that doesn't invalidate the existing answer, consider rephrasing your question to tell us what specific issues you have with your current implementation and clarify what metrics you would consider meeting the currently-vague "better" benchmark you've set forth.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, I didn't know about the Code Review community. I edited the title of this question because it was too generic, the title was this: `How to rewrite this javascript function that uses spread operator using C# code?` I edited in the intention to make this question more useful to others looking for a khapsack c# solution. I am already satisfied with the answer. You think I should leave the question the way it is?

Comment: Given that the question is now closed, it's probably fine to leave it as is, since the closure banner will serve as a message to any future readers that they should not ask similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a pretty nifty implementation here which runs through the problem quite quickly.

I can only see minor performance improvements in what you have here that would add fractional time to the execution.

```cs
int? result = MaxCollectableTreasure(new List<int?>() { 1, 3, 1, 8, 7 }, 3);

int? MaxCollectableTreasure(IReadOnlyList<int?> chests, int minutes)
{
    if (chests.Count == 1 && minutes > 0)
        return chests[0];

    int? firstElement = chests[0];
    var restOfList = chests.Skip(1);

    return MaxCollectableTreasuresRecursive(firstElement, restOfList, minutes);
}

int? MaxCollectableTreasuresRecursive(int? firstElement, IEnumerable<int?> chests, int minutes)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (minutes == 0 || firstElement is null) return 0;

        if (firstElement == 0)
        {
            firstElement = chests.FirstOrDefault();
            chests = chests.Skip(1);
            minutes -= 1;
            continue;
        }

        var left = firstElement + MaxCollectableTreasuresRecursive(0, chests, minutes - 1);
        var right = MaxCollectableTreasuresRecursive(chests.FirstOrDefault(), chests.Skip(1), minutes - 1);

        int leftAsInt = left ?? 0;
        int rightAsInt = right ?? 0;

        return Math.Max(leftAsInt, rightAsInt);
    }
}
```

The first would be that you don't need to `.Take().ToList()` on your approach to retrieving the chests, simply `.Skip()` on its own should do what you need.

In the calculation for the left value also, you prepend 0 to the chest and then do a skip 1 on it, so that could be removed to neaten that bit up.

Must say though, you've done a pretty neat interpretation of the Javascript equivalent!